# All possible photons wavelengths

Tags: visible-light, photons

As far as I know all photons come from electrons loosing their energy. I remember from physics and chemistry classes, that electron can loose or get only certain determined amount of energy. Also I remember that every nucleous has finite amount of energy  levels.  Since photon is a wave (and I might have read this somewhere) I've always imagined, that photon comes  from electron doing "wobbling" upon stabilizing on a lower orbit and that there is no other way for photon to be born.
These statements lead me to conclusion, that there is a finite amount of possible photons wavelengths. Is it so? If not, where am I wrong? Thank you

Comment: Your flaw lies in thinking that orbital transitions are the only process through which photons are created. Photons are created in numerous processes. For example, the emission of radiation when charged particles accelerate, Matter Anti-Matter annihilation. etc These photons can technically can have all possible wavelengths.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the change in orbital of an electron the only way a photon is created](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/200520/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Photons can come from a variety of sources, some of which are indeed transitions of electron levels (or nucleus levels or molecular levels), which are indeed discrete (it is also not because of wobbling).

The most common way of having photons of arbitrary wavelengths is via Bremsstrahlung radiation. This is the radiation obtained when a charge is accelerated, which can emit photons of pretty much any energy level.

Another thing to keep in mind is that the wavelength depends on the frame. Even if you use energy transitions, if the bound system considered is moving, the emitted photon will have its wavelength shifted, which could also here produce arbitrary wavelength depending on the speed.